# What Unity editor settings maximize the editor performance?

Tags: unity, performance, editors

I am teaching a Unity game development course through Zoom, and apparently the load of both Zoom and Unity is straining my 3 years old laptop. I would like to change some settings in the Unity editor in order to improve its overall response time. Note that I am not asking about game performance - only the performance of the editor itself (response time when opening tabs, compiling, etc.). One thing that I already did was to uncheck "auto-generate lighting" in all 3-D projects. What are some other general settings that can be changed so that the editor performance improves?

Comment: I find my 5 year old laptop does totally fine unless I’m in playmode. Perhaps enter playmode sparingly or prerecord the gameplay sequences. Make sure you’re not using any image processing effects in zoom. And turn on the setting to optimize for video in zoom. In unity, you can cap the frame rate and reduce the default quality settings. You can also change the resolution of the game window which will help considerably during playmode.

Comment: @AdamB Where exactly can I find these frame-rate and default-quality settings?

Comment: Most of these settings are in Quality/Graphics/Player tabs of the player settings window.

Comment: The resolution of the game window is right at top of game window